# Hide empty textBlock in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

How to make a textBlock auto hide if empty in windows phone 7 app (C#, silverlight, xaml)?

I know there's a similar question for WPF but it seems not applicable in silverlight.

Comment: Are you using databinding on the TextBlock or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a converter:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding YourString, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}" />

<UserControl.Resources>
    <converter:LengthConverter x:Key="LengthToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then the converter is:

```
public class LengthToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = (string)value;
        return text.Length > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You could make this slightly cleaner by binding to the text length directly:

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding YourString.Length, Converter={StaticResource LengthConverter}" />
```

In which case the converter becomes:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int length = (int)value;
        return length > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibilty.Collapsed;
    }
```

Find out more about Converters here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)